# replace all strings that contains a word in a PHP Array

Tags: php, sql, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to all URLs that contain `http://api.example.com/data/` to `https://example.com/data/`
in an array from a Database while using the Fat-Free Framework, the code iv tried below gives me

Internal Server Error, Array to string conversion

```
$f3->route('GET /details/@itemid',
    function($f3) {


$arr = array('result' => $f3->get('DBh')->exec('SELECT * FROM DB_table WHERE id=?',$f3->get('PARAMS.itemid')));

str_replace('http://api.example.com/data/', 'https://example.com/data/', $arr);

$f3->mset($arr);

        echo \Template::instance()->render('views/details.html');
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm guessing the str_replace() doesn't know what to do with $arr. Try doing a foreach loop and str_replace() individual rows.

Comment: This is all good, the only thing you're missing is to assign to your $arr the new values from the str_replace() -     
$arr = str_replace('http://api.example.com/data/', 'https://example.com/data/', $arr);

Comment: iv tried what you guys have suggested (see below) and its the same error (Internal Server Error, Array to string conversion)

```$f3->route('GET /details/@itemid',
    function($f3) {


$arr = array('result' => $f3->get('DBh')->exec('SELECT * FROM homebrews WHERE id=?',$f3->get('PARAMS.itemid')));

$arr = str_replace('http://api.pkg-zone.com/storedata/', 'https://pkg-zone.com/storedata/', $arr);

 $f3->mset($arr);

 echo \Template::instance()->render('views/details.html');
    }
);```

Comment: Don't add code in comments, it's unreadable. Also comments appear by order of votes, not chronologically. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've got a couple simple options to help with this. I'm also going to assume you mean to reference `$arr['result']` and not just `$arr` and I'd need to assume you're only looking for one column out of the db column. I'll call this column `url`.

### Option 1

```
foreach($arr['result'] as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value['url'])) {
        continue;
    }
    $arr['result'][$key]['url'] = str_replace('http://api.example.com/data/', 'https://example.com/data/', $value['url']);
}
```

### Option 2

```
foreach($arr['result'] as &$value) {
    if(empty($value['url'])) {
        continue;
    }
    $value['url'] = str_replace('http://api.example.com/data/', 'https://example.com/data/', $value['url']);
}
```

### Option 3

```
$arr['result'] = array_map(function($value) {
    $value['url'] = str_replace('http://api.example.com/data/', 'https://example.com/data/', $value['url']);
    return $value;
}, $arr['result']);
```

My personal preference for readability and simplicity is Option 2. I believe foreach statements have been optimized to actually run faster than array_map which is......interesting.